# Copy protecting a single page in PDF document using C#?

Tags: c#, itext, pdfsharp, copy-protection, pdfclown

Is it possible to restrict/disable copy/cut/print option (Copy Protect) for a single page in PDF document using C#?

I know it is very much possible to copy protect the whole PDF document using third party library like PDFSharp, PDFClown etc.

But all I want is just to copy protect a single page in PDF.

> Here is my requirement:
>
> - After a document is changed, it will be converted to PDF document and    will be sent for review process.
> - Reviewer will review the document and he/she will add his/her    signature to the first page of the document.
> - So, only that first page which contains the signature, should be copy/print protected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PDF protection by standard means (encryption according to section 7.6 of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) always refers to the whole document. That being said there are some tricks: Copy&paste can be prevented by simply creating unparsable text, and printing can be made more difficult by using an optional content group which is not active for printing. The latter trick can be worked around, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really find it helpful. But I need some more clarifications.Before that, Let me elaborate my requirement so that you can get more ideas to help me out. Please refer to my question again. Now please tell me, how i can adapt the above solution which you mentioned, into my problem. Please share any reference materials/links

Comment: Your requirements can't be met with PDF as defined in ISO-32000-1. You could probably get close by using a DRM solution, but you won't find any DRM products that are free. @mkl was referring to encryption as shown here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=219 By limiting the permissions, you can disable copy/assemble/..., but that's not a robust solution as many viewers do not respect the permission settings.